# Render a map of div and their title

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to simplify "renderTitle" and "renderComments" in a unique function in a React component:

```
renderTitle(dish) {
    return (
      <h2>
        Title array comment
      </h2>
    );
}
renderComments(dish) {
    return (
      dish.array.map(comment => {
        return (
          <div>
             hello
          </div>
        );
      })
    );
}
render() {
  return (
     {this.renderTitle(this.props.dish)}
     {this.renderComments(this.props.dish)}
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello Sara, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us what you have tried so far? Did you try something and it didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at below code where I used Fragment (react 16.x). And see how I merged the functions in your question.

```
renderItems(dish) {
    const comments = dish.array.map(comment => (<div>hello</div>))
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <h2>
            Title array comment
        </h2>
       {comments}
    </React.Fragment>
);}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use regular JavaScript expressions in the middle of JSX you have to wrap the JavaScript expression in `{}`.

Note that to return multiple elements on the same level you should either return an array or wrap them in a `Fragment`:

```
render() {
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>
          Title array comment
        </h2>
        {
          dish.array.map(comment => (
            <div>
               hello
            </div>
          ));
        }
      </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if `this.props.dish` is array.

```
renderTitle(dish) {
    return dish.map(i => {
        return <div>{i.title}</div>;/*this title may change*/
    });
}
renderComments(dish) {
    return dish.map(i => {
        return <div>{i.comment}</div>;/*this comment may change*/
    });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderTitle(this.props.dish)}
            {this.renderComments(this.props.dish)}
        </div>
    );
}
```